# is there any way to generate webkit idl from c++ source

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit, idl

I want to expose a c++ source library through JavaScript interfaces in webkit.

Is there any way to generate the webkit-IDL for this c++ source ? at least a skeleton code ?

OR - Is writing the IDLs manually the only way to do this ? no code generator for this ?

**Source: C++**

**Target: Webkit-IDL**

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write the IDL's manually, they then can be generated (fairly) easily for different targets (and integrated into webkit, chromium, and their alter-javascript-ego's JavaScriptCore and V8).